# How to test methods in a java project using a maven junit5 framework project in eclipse

Tags: maven, junit5

I created a new maven junit5 framework project to test existing java projects. I added the java project in build path of the newly created maven junit5 framework project. I right clicked the method I wanted to add junit test case for and selected new junit test case and changed the source folder to the new maven junit5 framework project src directory and left the rest of the options as default. Created the junit test and ran the test as a unit test without any issues(screenshot below). Running the same test using maven getting the error below. I added the surefire plugin in pom(below) but still getting the error below. Using eclipse.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Test set: com.build.VersionInfoTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.build.VersionInfoTest
com.build.VersionInfoTest  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/build/VersionInfo;
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.build.VersionInfo

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>UnitTesting</groupId>
<artifactId>com.unit.testing</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>com.unit.testing</name>
<description>Junit Tests</description>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.5.2</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.5.2</junit.platform.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

[image: run as junit passes]

Update : I cleaned up the pom(below) but now no tests discovered? when I run the project with junit the test is discovered?

```
  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --------------< UnitTesting:com.unit.testing >---------------
  [INFO] Building com.unit.testing 1.0-SNAPSHOT
  [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]----------------------       -----------
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources)      @ com.unit.testing ---
  [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
  [INFO] Copying 0 resource
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @     com.unit.testing ---
  [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-    testResources) @ com.unit.testing ---
  [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
  [INFO] Copying 0 resource
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ com.unit.testing ---
  [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) @   com.unit.testing ---
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO]  T E S T S
  [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Running com.build.VersionInfoTest
  [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time   elapsed: 0.002 s - in com.build.VersionInfoTest
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] Results:
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time: 1.955 s
  [INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-09T10:00:22-04:00
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


    <packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.target>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.6.0</junit.jupiter.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
  package com.dbb.build

  import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
  import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
  import com.dbb.build.VersionInfo;

  class VersionInfoTest {

VersionInfo versionInfo = VersionInfo.getInstance();

@Test
void getVersion() {
    String version = versionInfo.getVersion();
    System.out.println(version);
    assertNotNull(versionInfo.getVersion(), "expected a return value of"+version+"but was null");
}
  }
```

UPDATE:

```
  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default- testResources) @ DBB-Unit-Testing ---
  [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
  [INFO] Copying 0 resource
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ DBB-Unit-Testing ---
  [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
  [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Unit-Testing/target/test-classes
  [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
  [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
  [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
  [ERROR] /Unit-Testing/src/test/java/com/VersionInfoTest.java:[7,25]  cannot find symbol
   symbol:   class VersionInfo
   location: package com.build
  [ERROR] /Unit-Testing/src/test/java/com/build/VersionInfoTest.java: [11,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class VersionInfo
  location: class com.build.TestVersionInfo
 [ERROR] /Unit-Testing/src/test/java/com/ /build/VersionInfoTest.java:  [11,35] cannot find symbol
   symbol:   variable VersionInfo
   location: class com.build.TestVersionInfo
   [INFO] 3 errors
```

Solution: Using junit-platform-console-standalone-1.5.2.jar and run units via command line. Looks like if we have a non maven project junit-platform-console-standalone seems to be a better option.

Comment: Can you please add the error you've mentioned in the post? Cause I don't see the error ?

Comment: com.build.VersionInfoTest  Time elapsed: 0.002 s
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`: Lcom/build/VersionInfo;
Caused by: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`: com.build.VersionInfo

Comment: Then your build is broken..please full error message not only excerpts ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of some of my pom I use with Maven 3.x and tests executed as expected with JUnit 5 in Eclipse but also from command line:

Don't add too many Juniper artifacts, some will create some side effect if present.

Note also  the updated version of the surefire plugin with had some issue in the past with JUnit5

```
    <properties>
        <!-- ensure proper encoding of source and resource files in the project -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <junit-5.version>5.6.0</junit-5.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

UPDATE:

You can find a small example here: https://gist.github.com/asa-git/8e34bbc51b5fcb09b7fab3efdaaa73c9

Note that I am using maven version 3.6.3 and a JDK 8.

Furthermore, when running from the command line on windows (but likewise on other systems), you need to make sure your JDK is on your path before any other JSE installed on your system.

Comment: thank you. I update my comments above. no tests are discovered now?

Comment: can you share a simple version of your program ?

Comment: asa, I added the test I'm trying to run using junit5 and maven. I imported the project where the java classes are located( import com.dbb.build.VersionInfo) and got the instance of the method I'm writing the junit test for.

Comment: Also does it matter that the project I'm trying to write test for is using javase-1.7. and the maven project I created to write the junit tests is using javase-1.8?

Comment: i'll create a small test project when i get home and put it on github for you to download and try it.

Comment: Thanks asa that would be very helpful. Appreciate your help. So the example will be with a java project which is not a maven project and we create another maven project to write junit tests to test the methods in the java project?

Comment: Thanks asa, I think the issue with my project is that I have the source code in one java project and the junit unit test for that source code in another project. Although I added the source code java project to build path of the maven junit test project, I keep getting the error that I updated in the original question above.

Comment: in that case, your other project should be a maven project, which you would then include as a dependency in this one. check out some guides like the following one which will present you some of the basics of Maven: https://www.baeldung.com/maven

Comment: asa- thank you. True if I converted the project it would have worked.That project belong to the dev team and they are not wanting to convert the project to maven at this time. I plan on using junit-platform-console-standalone-1.5.2.jar and run units via command line. Looks like if we have a non maven project junit-platform-console-standalone seems to be a better option.